# How can I convert this JSON string into a struct?

Tags: json, go

How can I this JSON string into two distinct arrays? I want a bids array and an asks array, however, I am unsure. This is the JSON:

```
{

   "lastUpdateId":6219028865,
   "bids":[
         "45529.93000000",
         "0.59554000"
      ],
      [
         "45529.92000000",
         "0.04402000"
      ],
   ],
   "asks":[
      [
         "45529.94000000",
         "3.77220000"
      ],
      [
         "45529.95000000",
         "0.07800000"
      ],
   ]
}
```

I recieve the JSON from the request:

```
b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
```

How would I go about this process?

Comment: https://go.dev/blog/json

Comment: @Thomas I have tried and am still unsure, which is why I came here

Comment: Then please show what you have tried and where you got stuck. Right now the question is too vague.

Comment: Your `JSON` is invalid - it's missing `[` and has extraneous `,` in places. Once correct use online resources to help you convert it to a Go `struct` that is compatible with `json.Unmarshal`: https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```golang
type Output struct {
    LastUpdateId int64
    Bids         [][]string
    Asks         [][]string
}

// ...

var out Output
if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&out); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(out.Bids)
fmt.Println(out.Asks)
```